Should isMinifyEnabled=true exist in build.grade of library module?
I am using library modules in my apps.
I have isMinifyEnabled=true in my app level. I have (had) isMinifyEnabled=true also in my libraries. I did it thinking this needs to be done for the code that resides in the library to be minified.
This was working until AGP 8.3.0.
When upgrading to 8.4.0 I got build error:
Missing classes detected while running R8. 
Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in...

Removing the isMinifyEnabled from the libraries solves it. Examining the resulting apk shows that removing isMinifyEnabled from the libraries level did not cancel the minify of the libraries code. 
I am kind of describing here a solved issue that took me few hours to figure out. What I am looking for is confirmation that I got it right. That indeed there is no reason to have isMinifyEnabled=true in the libraries level.
Also, I would like to understand what was changed. What is that difference behind the fact that it worked on 8.3.0 but not on 8.4.0.

You are right to remove the minification flag by removing that flag
AGP 8.4.0 has some breaking changes which can be found here
Alternatively, you can look at keeping the flag and adding the proguard rules as required because that flag gives you massive size savings

Thanks. I am still a little confused by the last paragraph of your answer. Does the flag in library level still has influence on the size of the apk of the app that has the flag on its own level? Or do you mean that it will save size locally when developing? (which will not happen anyway on debug version).

As a good practice, you must minify your release builds to reduce app size

Of course. But I do not publish the libraries as stand alone. I publish the apps. What I am asking is does the flag in library level still does reduce the size of the apk of the app that has the flag on its own level? When removing the flag on the library level, I still did not see the library objects by their names in the apk.

Having the flag at the app level does the magic of reduction. As you see the changelog, by default libraries are shrunk, whether you put the flag or not. And if you need to customise what's exactly shrunk and what's not, you can use the proguard rules

If you see the link above, there's also a Gradle property you can enable for now, to see if this updation in the plugin is causing the issue. I'm sure that this is the issue, but just for your satisfaction
